# Swift: How to decode a JSON with a dictionary of dictionaries with each key being an incrementing number value?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, codable, decodable

I am new to Swift and I was assigned a task to decode this JSON:

```
 {
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "elements": {
            "E01": {
                    "title": "cars",
                    "items": ["honda", "toyota", "mercedes"],
                    "details": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "location": "toronto"
                    }
            },
            "E02": {
                    "title": "bagel types",
                    "items": ["plain", "grain", "toasted"],
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I played around with this and I figured out how to decode this JSON when `elements` is an array of dictionaries with no incrementing key value. This is when `elements` looks like this:

```
         "elements": [
            {
                "title": "cars",
                "items": ["honda", "toyota", "mercedes"],
                "details": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "location": "toronto"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "bagel types",
                "items": ["plain", "grain", "toasted"],
            }
        ]
```

Here is my code on how to decode the JSON when `elements` look like the JSON directly above:

**The classes I am decoding to:**

```
public class StructureContainer: Codable {
    let data: DataStructure
    
    init(data: DataStructure) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

public class DataStructure: Codable {
    let id: Int64?
    let elements: [ElementStructure]?
    
    init(id: Int64?, elements: [ElementStructure]?) {
        self.id = id
        self.elements = elements
    }
}

public class ElementStructure: Codable {
    let title: String?
    let items: [String]?
    let details: DetailStructure?
    
    init(title: String?, items: [String]?, details: DetailStructure?) {
        self.title = title
        self.items = items
        self.details = details
    }
}

public class DetailStructure: Codable {
    var id: Int64?
    var location: String?
    
    init(id: Int64?, location: String?) {
        self.id = id
        self.location = location
    }
}
```

**How I am decoding this:**

```
func parseJSONLocally() {
    do {
        // JSONText is the variable that contains the JSON string
        let jsonData = JSONText.data(using: .utf8)!
        // dataInstance is the variable of type Structure that stores the parsed object.
        dataInstance = try JSONDecoder().decode(StructureContainer.self, from: jsonData)
    }
    catch {
        print("error", error)
    }
}
```

I am able to successfully decode this when elements is an array of dictionaries with no incrementing key. However, I am lost on how to decode this when elements is a dictionary of dictionaries with each key incrementing.

I have found similar questions to this on StackOverflow but I don't think I have seen my exact problem. I am also new to Swift so I might be missing some knowledge somewhere. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you only get two keys, `E9864` and `E53981`, how do you want for them to be decoded? As an array with two elements? Fail the decoding?

Answer (score 1):

First of all `Int64` makes no sense. On all modern computers `Int64` is equal to `Int`. And declare only the properties as optional which can be `nil`

Assuming the dictionary keys don't matter implement `init(from decoder` to decode the dictionary version, decode `[String:ElementStructure]` and assign the dictionary `values` sorted by the `keys` to `elements`

```
public class DataStructure: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let elements: [ElementStructure] // why not just Element?
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case id, elements }
    
    required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey:  .id)
        let elementData = try container.decode([String:ElementStructure].self, forKey: .elements)
        let sortedkeys = elementData.keys.sorted{ $0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending }
        elements = sortedkeys.map{elementData[$0]!}
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will put the elements in random order which doesn't really match the "incrementing key." I think you'll need to sort this by key to preserve the order (looking at the keys, they should sort correctly).

Comment: @RobNapier Good point, thanks, answer updated.